# Open failed on >infile.nc< No such file or Directory using Cygwin64

Tags: cdo-climate

I have installed cygwin64 in Windows 10 all packages and the installation was successfully. I have also downloaded CDO version 1.9.8 and copied to to bin folder (C:/Cygwin64/Bin). I also change my directory to C:/Cygwin64/Bin but when i am using the cdo sinfon operator, it gives me the bellow error:

```
Ayoubi@Ayoubi /usr/bin
$ cdo sinfov pr_WAS44MIROCMIROC5
cdo    sinfon: Open failed on >pr_WAS44MIROCMIROC5<
               No such file or directory
```

you can see the CDO -v information[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRWz5.png) and error in the attached image.

I have deleted and reinstall the cygwin64 many times but it does not solve the problem. Could you please help and explain how i can overcome this problem.

I am sorry if this is the basic question but i am new in programming and scripting.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Try to avoid images and post plain text. Wrap your code and the output in code fences, so the text is easier to read.

Comment: To be honest, I think it is far easier these days to install the unbuntu subsystem under windows - you then get an ubuntu terminal and can install everything you need including cdo with apt-get...